# Prove that $T_a$ does not convergent in operator norm.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $H:=L^2 (\mathbb{R})$ and for $a>0$,$\,$$f\in H$, $T_a f(x):=\frac{1}{2a}\int _{x-a}^{x+a} f(y)dy$.
Then prove that $T_a \not \to id$ as $a\to 0$  in operator norm.

My idea:
I proved $T_a$ strongly convergent to $id$ by using Schwartz's inequality and Fubini's theorem.
If $T_a$ are compact operator and $T_a$ convergent $id$, $id$ is compact operator. It is a contradiction to dimension of $H$.
So, I tried to prove $T_a$ is compact operator, but I can't.

Comment: what is the question, exactly?

Comment: Question:Prove that $\lim_{a\to 0}||T_a-id||\not =0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each $a>0$, notice that $T_a$ is a [multiplier operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplier_(Fourier_analysis)) of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ whose multiplier is:
$$m_a :\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}, \xi\mapsto\frac{\sin(2\pi a\xi)}{2\pi a\xi},$$
i.e.:
$$\forall f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}), T_a(f) = \left(\frac{1}{2a}\chi_{[-a,a]}\right)*f = \mathcal{F^{-1}_\xi}\left(\frac{\sin(2\pi a\xi)}{2\pi a\xi}\right)*f \\ = \mathcal{F^{-1}_\xi}\left(m_a(\xi)\right)*\mathcal{F^{-1}_\xi}(\hat{f}) = \mathcal{F^{-1}_\xi}\left(m_a(\xi)\hat{f}(\xi)\right),$$
where the Fourier transform is normalized in the following manner:
$$\forall f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}), \forall \xi \in \mathbb{R},  \mathcal{F}(f)(\xi):=\hat{f}(\xi):=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(t)e^{-2\pi i \xi t}\operatorname{d}t.$$ 
Then $T_a-I$ is a multiplier operator of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ whose multiplier is $m_a-1$. Then, remembering that if $T$ is a multiplier operator of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ whose multiplier is $m$ it holds that $\|T\|_{2\rightarrow2}=\|m\|_\infty,$ we get that:
$$\|T_a-I\|_{2\rightarrow2} =\|m_a-1\|_\infty\ge\lim_{\xi\rightarrow\infty}\left|\frac{\sin(2\pi a\xi)}{2\pi a\xi}-1\right| =1,$$
So:
$$\liminf_{a\rightarrow0^+}\|T_a-I\|_{2\rightarrow2}\ge1$$
and then:
$$\|T_a-I\|_{2\rightarrow2}\not\rightarrow0, a\rightarrow0^+$$

Answer (score 1):

A simpler version of the same argument in another answer: For $a>0$ let $$f_a=a^{-1/2}\chi_{(0,a)},$$ so $||f_a||_2=1$..

It's easy to see that $$T_af_a(x)\ge\frac14 a^{-1/2},\quad(-a/2<x<0).$$
Hence $||f_a-T_af_a||_2\ge c>0$.

Comment: What's the problem with that? Yes, it's simpler than the other correct answers... (I looked at it when I saw the downvote, fixed a typo)

Answer (score 0):

Let $f_a(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2a}}, & -a\leq x\leq a\\
0, & others
\end{cases},$ then $\|f_a\|_2=1$, $T_af_a(x)=\frac{2a-x}{2a\sqrt{2a}}$ for $x\in [0,2a]$, and 
$$\|T_a-id\|^2\geq \|T_af_a-f_a\|_2^2\geq \int_{0}^a|T_af_a(x)-f_a(x)|^2dx=\int_{0}^a\frac{x^2}{(2a)^3}dx=\frac{1}{24}$$

Comment: When you write $\|f_a\|$ = 1, which norm are you using?

Comment: Sorry, see the update.

Comment: Why the downvote? People should leave a comment explaining what the problem is - seems fine to me. (I haven't looked carefully at the calculations, but that $f_a$ certainly does give a counterexample - if there's a problem with the details it's easily fixed.)